# How to search efficiently return all the values for keys which are in a arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I am having an arraylist which contains a list of numbers. I want to get all the values from the HashMap which has the keys which are in the array list.

For example say the array list contains `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`  list

I want to get all the values for the keys  `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`  map

So currently I am implementing

```
for (i=0;i<list.size;i++){

           map_new.put(list.get(),map.get(list.get()))
}
```

Is there any efficient way to do this?

Comment: Does this code even _run_?  Whose `put()` method are you calling here?

Comment: so you generally want as result a map with the keys from list and values from a map which also has the same keys?

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do, you really can't get much more efficiency.  You could use `for (ElementType e : list)` instead of a `for` loop with an index, which might be a tiny bit faster in addition to being more readable.  It would help if you posted code that actually compiles, though.

Comment: Assuming that above code compiles, the approach is decent. Any other approach, on the parameter of efficiency, will perform similar to this.

Comment: In your code, what if `map.get` does not return value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code basically assumes that `map.get(list.get())` always returns a value, you can try the following code which first filters the not `null` values from the `list` object and then adds to the new `Map`:

```
Map<String, Integer> newMap = list.stream().
    filter(key -> (map.get(key) != null)).//filter values not present in Map
     collect(Collectors.toMap(t -> t, t -> map.get(t)));//now collect to a new Map
```

---

In case, if `map.get(list.get())` returns `null`, your code **creates a `Map` with `null` values** in it for which you might end up doing `null` checks, which is not good, rather you can ensure that your newly created `Map` always contains a value for each key.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the signature of list and the map are as following

```
List<Integer> list;
Map<Integer, Integer> map;
```

You can use following

```
for(int a : list){
   Integer b = map.get(a);
   if(b != null)
       // b is your desired value you can store in another collection
}
```

Which is similar to the procedure you have already used.

As you can access the map in `O(1)` so the complexity of this code will be `O(listsize)`

Answer (score 0):

There is not much you can do for efficiency. Still couple of small things you can do considering code example you have given above:

1) Change your for loop to

```
for(Long num : list)
```

instead of iterating using index, this will reduce you get calls over list.

2) You can update the existing map , so that you even do not need to iterate.

```
map.keySet().retainAll(list);
for(Long key: map.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(map.get(key));
}
```

With this existing map will contain only those data whose keys are present in list, but you should use it carefully depending upon rest of the code logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can capitalize on the fact that the keyset of a map is backed by the map itself and modifications to the keyset will reflect back to the map itself. This way, you can use the `retainAll()` method of the `Set` interface to reduce the map with a single line of code. Here is an example:

```
final Map<Integer, String> m = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
m.put(1, "A");
m.put(2, "B");
m.put(3, "C");
m.put(4, "D");
m.put(5, "E");

final List<Integer> al = Arrays.asList(new Integer[] { 2, 4, 5 });

System.out.println(m);
m.keySet().retainAll(al);
System.out.println(m);
```

This will output:

```
{1=A, 2=B, 3=C, 4=D, 5=E}
{2=B, 4=D, 5=E}
```